# Installing a strong-tie post anchor on unlevel concrete

Tags: concrete, fence

I'm building a short (3.5 ft) fence in my front yard. I have most of the posts sunk in dirt holes, but two of them will need to be mounted on a concrete slab.

The problem is that the slab has a slight slope to it and the post brackets I have will cause the posts to not be completely vertical.

These are [the brackets](http://www.homedepot.com/p/Simpson-Strong-Tie-12-Gauge-Black-Powder-Coated-E-Z-Base-FPBB44/100655350) I bought.

Is there something I can put under this bracket/anchor to make it sit level?

Comment: Why not cut a slight bevel in the bottom of the post to bring it back to level?

Comment: The anchor is a tight fit and the bottom of the anchor is metal so either way I can think of doing that wouldn't work, unfortunately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One or two galvanized or stainless-steel washers between the post base and the concrete should do. The latter are thinner and would allow finer angle adjustment. If you don't like the look of the gap underneath, fill it with a fine bead of gray caulk.

That said, there's probably plenty of slop against the post that you can plumb it and add the side screws to keep it plumb even if the base is slightly out of level.

To really make it solid with either approach, use heavy-duty construction adhesive between the base and the post.

Comment: I actually thought of using washers but thought it might be too "hacky". Nice to hear someone else suggest it.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by slop against the post?

Comment: It's unlikely that the post will perfectly (snugly) fit in the base, and that you wouldn't be able to tilt it a small amount equivalent to the slope in the slab.

Comment: I see. I actually tried putting the post on the anchor already and it's a very tight fit-- I actually had to pound it in.

Comment: Then your path is clear. :)

Comment: As others have mentioned, washers will corrode away.  Further, mixing metals (here, stainless and zinc galvanizing) too far apart on the electromotive scale will cause more rapid corrosion.

Comment: You might try using pennies as spacers. They will not rust, ever.

Comment: The washers under my community mailbox pedestal have been fine for a decade or more. Unless you're on a saltwater beach it's not really a concern.

Comment: The washers would be to get the post aligned, @Technophile. Once it's screwed in they can be removed. Except they can't. So, if/when the washers erode away, the screws through the post base will continue to hold the post vertical.

Comment: The problem with cutting the post on a slop to match a sloped base is where the force will be. Instead of the post putting its force downward onto the entire base. It will force it into the lowest side. Washers isn't a bad idea and proper stainless steel washers will not rust away. The hot dipped galvanized bases would rust first.

Answer (score 2):

i faced the same issue (for a small double L fence I did to enclose garbage cans on the side of my house) and came up with a bunch of solutions and tried only one but perhaps some of these will suit others peoples needs:

---

1. As previously discussed...Washers were my number thought, which i actually marked as too "hacky" or simply inadequate .. so I was then also thinking about metal plates of various thicknesses but the variety i needed i couldn't find so..

---

2. I then started to think that I can mark bracket dims on concrete and chisel a bit of concrete on the higher end perhaps can use some rotary with an abrasive, which seemed somewhat dangerous because if you do a bit too much of "taking out part" then you wont be able to put it back. Or at least do it easily...

---

3. Then I thought that people must have had these issues before me and surely somebody tried to commercialize and i found these folks - https://www.colorguardrailing.com/s/The-Patriot-Leveling-Post-Bracket-Installation-Instructions.pdf

---

4. Following #3 discovery I realized that I can perhaps do a version of it myself. Basically get a couple of small drop in or wedge anchors or similar. Drill two holes on the lower part adjusting holes depths for slope so that anchors stick out just enough to make everything level. Insert anchors perhaps then secure with an adhesive. Wait till all cures.

---

5. But! As I already bought my brackets ([of this type](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Simpson-Strong-Tie-ABA-ZMAX-Galvanized-Adjustable-Standoff-Post-Base-for-4x4-Actual-Rough-Lumber-ABA44RZ/205227038)) and wanted to just "do my thing" right here right now, without going back to the store i thought about it some more looking at my brackets (probably shoulve started there), and perhaps this is sad, but I realized that since my brackets are not fully enclosed, just two sides, I can actually situate my brackets such that its top two parts that stick out (arms?) are going parallel to slope, in such case i can tilt the pole however I need against the slope. So i measured out slope angle, cut the bottom of my poll using my miter saw to that angle and just put it on top of my sloped bracket that I already attached and secured.

---

PS
with my chosen solution i did need to grind parts of brackets "arms" (good thing i had the tools for it) so that they were even with the poll so i was able to plumb my pickets

Answer (score 1):

Pour a bit of concrete or leveling compound under the anchor.  Washers *will* rust away.

Comment: I used some cement patching compound with the PVC(?) bonding compound in it, and tapered the edges at (an arbitrary) 45 degrees.  Wait until it's fully set then tighten the nuts.  Very solid and looks good.  The gray of the fresh compound did not immediately match the gray of the weathered concrete, but give it some time.