# Mount wooden post onto uneven concrete

Tags: concrete, fence, post, mount

Hi I'm wanting to mount a 112x112x3000 post onto a concrete slab.  I have purchased L shaped brackets to do the job.  Because the post will sit at the edge of the concrete I can install at most three brackets as there isn't enough room on the fourth side for a bracket.  Also I could only find L brackets, they don't sell the sleeve type where I am.

The issue is check that the post is level I realized that the concrete slab is not level on one side. its only out by a little but there is a very small gap under the post.  So I am wondering what I should do.  I figure I have four options.

1. Use self leveling grout level the slab surface
2. Grind the slab level
3. Sand the edge of the post until it sits level on the slab
4. I don't need to worry about it as the brakets will hold the post in place.

To me option 3 sounds the most viable if the post must site level on the slab but if I don't need to do anything because the brackets will keep it in place then thats easier.

There isn't going to be much load on the post as it isn't going to be supporting a gate, only three 50x100 rails and 1.8m palings, pretty standard.

I would appreciate some advice on the matter thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Installing a strong-tie post anchor on unlevel concrete](http://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/79705/installing-a-strong-tie-post-anchor-on-unlevel-concrete?rq=1)